# Как спарсить на сайте строку без стилей и всякого мусора в строке?

Tags: javascript

с сайте беру строку и записываю ее в таблицу, например строка:

```
АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО "КОРПОРАЦИЯ КОСМИЧЕСКИХ <span class="pinkBg">СИСТЕМ</span> СПЕЦИАЛЬНОГО НАЗНАЧЕНИЯ "КОМЕТА"
```

В таблицу попадает строка с прописанными стилями. Пишу через replace, но не понимаю как прописать все исключения, и к тому же у каждой строки может быть любой другой стиль, может есть какое-то другое решение?

Так хватаю данные из строки:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var textResp=response.getContentText();

//заказчик
start = textResp.indexOf('Заказчик:',end);
start = textResp.indexOf('return false;"',end);
start = textResp.indexOf('>',start)+1;
end = textResp.indexOf('</a>',start);
name = textResp.substring(start,end);
name = name.replace(/<span class="pinkBg">/g,'');
name = name.replace('</span>','');
name = name.trim();
cell.setValue(name);
cell=cell.offset(0,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, если я вас правильно понял:

```js
let str = "КАКАЯ-ТО СТРОКА С ТЕГОМ ВНУТРИ <span class='test'>atata</span> И ДАЛЕЕ.";
console.log(str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,''));
```

Comment: Сейчас я получаю `var name="КАКАЯ-ТО СТРОКА С ТЕГОМ ВНУТРИ <span class='test'>atata</span> И ДАЛЕЕ."`, в которой записан текст от такого знака до такого. И мне надо это значение передать в `cell`. Если прописывать `name = console.log(name.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,''));
cell.setValue(name);` то значение `undefined`. Может я что-то не так делаю....

Comment: @ЕвгенияБалабанова, я не понимаю вас)  console.log()  тут для наглядности примера. Вам же нужно var name = name.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,''); cell.setValue(name);